# Query returns boolean value in spring jdbctemplate?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc

Here I am writing Database application.In that I want to know if the `ENDDATETIME` column becomes null then i want to find that record and if there is any record like that then I want to return false,or if there is no records like that then I want to return true.

Because this query is for validating the user.If the user is alredy logined then `ENDDATETIME` will become null, if he logedout then `ENDDATETIME` column contains date. so if the `ENDDATETIME` column contains null then I will not allow him to login.

So I wrote the following query for that.

```
@Override
public boolean isUserAlreadyLoggedIn(int userId) {
    String sql="select USERID from useraudit where USERID=? ENDDATETIME is null";
    //getJdbcTemplate().        
    return false;
}
```

Please suggest me the correct way.

Comment: Did you tried anything ? There is enough tutorial on internet for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this approach:

```
String sql = "SELECT count(*) from useraudit where USERID=? AND ENDDATETIME is null";
boolean result = false;

int count = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(
                    sql, new Object[] { userId }, Integer.class);

if (count > 0) {
    result = true;
}

return result;
```

Comment: Let me try with this

Comment: Actually queryForObject will return only one value right?

Comment: Also add the AND @XING said

Comment: @mike will return the number of records where the condition is right, in your scenario or 1 or 0

Comment: or just return count > 0

Answer (score 1):

Your query is having a missing `and` clause. Use this:

```
select USERID from useraudit where USERID=? and ENDDATETIME is null
```